# Where can I see the output if I put a console.log in vue.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Vue cli 3 UI for a project and I need to problem some variables inside a wenpack plugin.

My instinct was to use console.log but I can't figure where the output would go

If not console.log is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will output to where the project is built/served.

So if you run the serve task of in the Vue CLI UI, it will print in the UI output window.

Or you can run `npm run serve` from your own terminal in the project folder, and it will print out in that terminal.

Comment: Should be able to see output from the UI but had so many warnings that it got hidden. 'npm run serve' did exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: @James what if we want to see after running **npm run build**.

Answer (score -2):

You can use console.log and the output will show in the console just like normal jquery or javascript.